# How do I use field_view_field inside a custom views .tpl?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a view set up that uses an image from a node, I have customized the views-view-field.tpl to change the url the image links to dependent on the content type. I am trying to print out the picture using field_view_field in the .tpl, but its just printing out "array". Here is what I'm working with.

```
<?php if ($row->node_type =='article'): ?>
<a href="http://www.someurl.com"><?php print field_view_field('node', $row, 'field_field_image');?></a>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. First I did a node load:

```
<?php $node = node_load($row->nid);?>
```

Then I had to wrap my `field_view_field` in a `drupal_render`, finally I added my image style name in the display parameter, like this:

```
<?php print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image', 'image_style'));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Print out the field using `print_r()`. You will probably find that there are safe and raw values at the very least and it will be most likely the safe value you want.

EDIT:

In the comments oobie11 points to [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way). Bookmark this :)

Looking at the documentation for [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) tells me that the second argument is the actual entity. I don't think for this purpose the `$row` variable counts as an entity. You will need to do a `node_load` first getting the nid from the `$row` and pass the returned node to `field_view_field`.

Comment: Wont that restrict me to one language?

Comment: ah, you can use something like $user->language to access the correct language. You're right, it will be a language component to the array.

Comment: I'll see if I can find an example, I'm sure I've done it in the past.

Comment: I read here (http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way), that field_view_field was the best way to do this. Not sure if the are correct, but it sounded good.

Comment: Ah I think I see what's wrong here.  I'll edit the original answer.

Comment: So I did a node_load `<?php 
$node = node_load($row->nid);
?>` and changed my field_view_field accordingly `<php print field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image');?>` and no luck. :(